# How to prevent the error: null > 0 java

Tags: java, if-statement, null

I currently have an enumlist. The enumlist gets filled at random, so there is a possibility that one has the value `null`. That is logical because it doesn't get filled.

The problem is further in my code I have:

```
if (player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK) > 0) {
}
```

Java throws a `NullPointerException`. Is there something I could add to the if-statement to prevent this error?

Comment: `if( player.Enumlist() != null && player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK) > 0) {`

Comment: you can use `assert player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK)!=null` maybe or `if(player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK)!=null && player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK) > 0) { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: aw thanks! Great thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If `get(CART_BLACK)` may return null:**

Get the value before the condition and replace it with a negative value if it's null:

```
Integer cartBlack = player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK);
if (cartBlack == null) cartBlack = -1;

if (cartBlack > 0) {
```

---

**If `player.Enumlist()` may return null**

Similar, but not quite identical:

```
final Enumlist list = player.Enumlist();
final int cartBlack = list == null ? -1 : list.get(CART_BLACK);

if (cartBlack > 0) {
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to guard against *nullity*:

```
if(player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK) != null && 
       player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK) > 0) {...}
```

or a more efficient version:

```
Integer temp = player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK);
if (temp != null && temp > 0){...}
```

Comment: More efficient, I am not sure (is the invocation expensive ? probably not if it is a getter) but more DRY it is sure !

Comment: @davidxxx the invocation need not be expensive for the second approach to be more efficient. not calling a method is more efficient than calling a method ;-), and yes good shout on the DRY principle!.

Comment: Fundamentally you are not wrong but on what I would stress on is that the  advantage of the second way is overall the no dupe : )

Answer (score 1):

```
if( player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK) != null && player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK) > 0) {

}
```

This will work because ifs are checked from left to right, and if one condition fails the rest won't be evaluated and you won't get the NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Correcting the issue at the end makes the trick but it is not fine because it means that it may occur in other invocations.  Besides, as a consequence, you may finish by overusing not null guards as you will never know if the `null` is a normal case.

So you should favor the use of `Optional` (Java 8 or Guava) as return rather than `null` to make your API clearer (it may return an empty thing so convey that) and more robust (the contained object has to be specifically unwrapped).
For example :

```
Optional<Integer> optValue = player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK);
optValue.filter(v -> v > 0)
        .ifPresent( v -> ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do Null Checking:

```
if (player == null || player.Enumlist () == null) {
    throw new Exception("Player or Enumlist cannot be null");
}
```

You should also check that the `Integer` value is not `null`, but I guess that would be pretty weird if you wrote the code.

You are using `get` which could give you an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` eventually. You could check that using the `size` method or using `streams`.

```
If (player.Enumlist().size() > CART_BLACK && player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK) != null && player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK) > 0) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check for Null also handle the exception using try..catch block

```
   try
    {
      if( player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK)!=null && player.Enumlist().get(CART_BLACK) > 0) 
        {
        }
    }
    catch(NullPointerException)
    {
    //handle exception here
    }
```